# GIMP Windows Placement when Opened in Unity

Tags: unity, compiz, gimp

I have just installed Natty Narwhal replacing my Lucid Lynx system.
I use GIMP so much, and found that in Unity, when opening GIMP (and actually any applications, I think), the windows placements are kind of less consistent compared to Ubuntu Classic.

I used to place the **Toolbox** window in the left side of desktop, the **Layers, Channels, Paths, Undo - Brushes, Patterns, Gradients** window in the right side, and resize the main window till it filled the gap between the both windows, and the windows will open in that position when I open GIMP.

However, things seem to work differently under Unity. When opening GIMP, the windows are always pushed to the right (looks like it is because of the launcher), even after I set them to fully occupy the desktop (over or alongside the launcher) and close it to 'save the configuration' before reopen it.

Are there any workarounds or solutions on this?
I want GIMP to be ready to be used without having to move the three windows to the desired place right after it is opened.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is a Compiz issue rather than Unity - does it work as expected in Ubuntu Classic?

Comment: @Oxwivi Yes, I tried it in Ubuntu Classic session and it works as expected, just like it works in Lucid.

Comment: I did a search on Launchpad and did not find this issue there. Maybe you could file a bug report?

Comment: As I expected, it's to do with how Compiz and Metacity handles window placement. I don't know if there are any rules to make Compiz act like Metacity, but specifically ask for it on Ask Ubuntu and try to contact Compiz developers on Launchpad.

Answer (score 2):

As a result of this discussion, I was thinking a little about GIMP window placement under Unity.  I do not disagree with the assertion that Compiz is responsible for the issue.  However, after taking a slightly deeper look, this is what I found:
[image]
In light of the above pic, I am now curious to know how Workspaces are managed under Unity.  It seems that is may be an issue with how Compiz's window placement interacts with the management of workspaces.  Does this seem to be a reasonable way of looking at this issue?